# What happened to Naegling and the energy in its gem?

Tags: inheritance-cycle

In *Brisingr*, Oromis's sword Naegling falls from his hand during an aerial battle immediately before he is killed. It would be one thing for a Rider's sword to be lost forever, but in the case of Naegling there is also a mind-boggling amount of energy stored in the diamond in its hilt.

During the century or so in which he hid with his dragon Glaedr in Du Weldenvarden, he, Glaedr, and several elves besides regularly added energy to the gem. The amount of strength the dragon alone could contribute every day would be staggering, even if it was only for one year; with all of them, over such a long period of time, Naegling's diamond must have been one of the most powerful objects in the world.

Given this, it's shocking to think that it was simply left where it fell and no one went to recover it. Nothing more is told in the series as far as I am aware, so what happened?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### This is the subject of a future book

> **Q: Well another ‘no comment’ is coming because of this question: What happened to Oromis’s sword?**
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *Great question. I know exactly what happened to it. Something I’ll probably be writing about at some point, past that… no comment.*

> **So it is still in your mind, it did go somewhere.**
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *Oh yeah, I don’t forget magical swords.*
> <sub>[2013 Interview](https://www.paolini.net/2016/03/23/qas-naegling-female-riders-doru-araeba/)</sub>

> **Q: What happened with the sword Naegling? Did someone take it along with all the power inside it?**
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *Yes.*
> <sub>[March 2016](https://www.paolini.net/2016/03/23/qas-naegling-female-riders-doru-araeba/)</sub>

> **Q: I always wanted to know the English translation of Oromis’ sword Naegling? Just as Eragon’s sword Brisingr is translated to mean “fire” and Zar’roc is translated to mean “misery” I figured Oromis’ sword must also have a meaning. I looked in the back of each book where the Ancient Language glossary was and I never found a translation for it!**
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *You're the first person to ask that! And I'd love to tell you, but unfortunately I can't because . . . it's an important plot point in a story I hope to write one day. Remember, Oromis dropped Naegling when Murtagh killed him? Whatever happened to it, I wonder? . . .*
> <sub>[Reddit AMA May 2016](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fantasy/comments/4i0tf1/hey_reddit_im_fantasy_author_christopher/d2w1l1g/?context=3)</sub>

> **Q: Hey this is a question that I have been thinking about sense the end of inheritance.  It was stated that a ton of riders swords were found in galbatorix's personal items, was one of them undbitr, Broms sword? And was Oromiss sword in there too?**
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *Oromis's sword was not in that collection. No comment re: Undbitr.*
> <sub>[Twitter November 2018](https://twitter.com/paolini/status/1064314199235547137)</sub>

> **Q: We know this is volume 1. . . . Is there anything you can tell us about what we can look forward to next?**
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *Heh. Right now I’m working hard on finishing up a massive sci-fi novel I’ve been focused on for a few years. After that, there are a whole host of stories I would like to write, including volume 2 of Tales from Alagaësia. In it, readers can expect some very new, very exciting stories, including—I hope—one about a dwarf detective and one about the fate of Oromis’s sword.*
> <sub>[Penguin Books Australia interview January 2019](https://www.penguin.com.au/articles/2116-a-conversation-with-christopher-paolini)</sub>

> **Q: I just finished reading book 3 again yesterday and there was no translation for Naegling, Undbitr and Támerlein. What do those sword names mean in the ancient language?**
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *Undbitr = Void/nothingness-Biter. Albitr = All-Biter. Naegling = roughly means 'bright nail'. Támerlein = meaning not yet given.*
> <sub>[Twitter January 2020](https://twitter.com/paolini/status/1484334071236861959)</sub>

> **Q: What happened to the Belt of Beloth the Wise and to Oromis's body and sword?**
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *The belt is Book Five, you'll find out in Book Five. The sword is something I've actually always wanted to write a certain story about. I have the story planned out, but as as of the end of Inheritance it hadn't been recovered. I don't want to give you any details but that that tells you at least where I'm thinking. As for Oromis's body, this was the first draft of Inheritance. I wrote a scene where I mentioned that the elves buried Oromis under a tree by Gil'ead.*
>
> **Q: So then his sword would have been recovered with all the energy as well?**
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *If it were recovered then whatever energy was in the sword would still be in the sword.*
> <sub>[July 2021 MCAlagaesia Tweetstorm Livestream](https://youtu.be/qklmMLP5KeI?t=12555)</sub>

> **Q: Will we ever find out what happened to Naegling?**
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *Yup. Have a whole book planned about it. Nearly wrote it right after Inheritance.*
> <sub>[Twitter August 2023](https://twitter.com/paolini/status/1693290495672484308)</sub>

> **Q: Will we ever get more stories on Oromis?**
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *Yes. Including one that's tangential to Oromis. For a very long time right when I finished Inheritance, I've been wanting to write a story about what happened to Oromis's Sword. Actually, I don't know if I've ever actually said that live, but yeah, that's a story I've been waiting to write for a very long time.*
> <sub>[September 2023 TikTok Live Q&A](https://youtu.be/JKWXIP4FrCw?t=1782)</sub>

> **Q: Tales from Alagaësia Volume Two, is the plan still that it's going to be about the Sword and the Dwarf detective?**
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *The sword is probably going to end up being a full-sized book. But the dwarf detective, yes, and probably a number of other stories compared with that. And I'm hoping actually to tackle it pretty soon, so...*
> <sub>[November 2023 Interview](https://www.reddit.com/r/Eragon/comments/17wqekv/questions_and_answers_with_christopher_paolini/)</sub>

> **Q: Was the "yellow gem" [that Murtagh finds in *Murtagh*] the diamond of Oromis's sword Naegling?**
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *No*
> <sub>[November 2023 Reddit AMA](https://www.reddit.com/r/Eragon/comments/184f4wc/ama_christopher_paolini_1pm_est11am_mst/kav6xnk/?context=3)</sub>

> **Q: You've said recently that Book Six is set 10 or 16 years after the Inheritance Cycle. Relative to that can you place some of your other past and future books, such as the Eragon-Arya book, the Angela book, and Eragon's Guide to Alagaësia? Do these three take place before or after Book Six?**
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *Eragon/Arya would be post Book 6. Eragon's Guide is contemporary with Book 6. Angela and Oromis's sword are pre Book 6 (which is why I'm debating writing them before following up Murtagh directly).*
> <sub>[November 2023 Reddit AMA](https://www.reddit.com/r/Eragon/comments/184f4wc/ama_christopher_paolini_1pm_est11am_mst/kav5w1l/?context=3)</sub>

> **Q: Was the "yellow gem" [that Murtagh finds] the diamond of Oromis's sword Naegling?**
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *No*
> <sub>[November 2023 Reddit AMA](https://www.reddit.com/r/Eragon/comments/184f4wc/ama_christopher_paolini_1pm_est11am_mst/kav6xnk/?context=3)</sub>

**So to recap:**

- It was not recovered by anyone until after the end of *Inheritance*
- The sword still has its energy in it
- The diamond Murtagh finds isn't from the sword
- Subject of a future story
- Christopher was ready to write this story immediately after *Inheritance*
- This story will be its own full-sized book
- This story will be set prior to Book Six

Comment: @EthanChan - These are direct quotes and should not be edited.

Answer (score 3):

### It is likely Murtagh recovered it after the battle and took it to Galbatorix.

Christopher Paolini said that someone had it:

> **Q:** What happened with the sword Naegling? Did someone take it along with all the power inside it?
>
> **A:** Yes.
> <sub>[Q&As with Christopher - paolini.net](https://www.paolini.net/2016/03/23/qas-naegling-female-riders-doru-araeba/)</sub>

And when they defeated Galbatorix, they recovered hundreds of swords.

> They also recovered several hundred Riders’ swords: swords of every color and shape, made for both humans and elves. It was a breathtaking find. Eragon and Saphira personally carried the weapons to the castle where the Eldunarí were, in anticipation of the day when they would again be needed by Riders.
> <sub>*Inheritance - Pieces on a Board*</sub>

So while it is never said explicitly, this is the most likely scenario.

Comment: This is wrong..